# How to apply streaming in azure openai dotnet web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-openai

I want to create a web api backend that stream openai completion responses.

How can I apply the following solution to a web api action in controller?

```
var client = new OpenAIClient(nonAzureOpenAIApiKey, new OpenAIClientOptions());
var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
{
    DeploymentName = "gpt-3.5-turbo", // Use DeploymentName for "model" with non-Azure clients
    Messages =
    {
        new ChatRequestSystemMessage("You are a helpful assistant. You will talk like a pirate."),
        new ChatRequestUserMessage("Can you help me?"),
        new ChatRequestAssistantMessage("Arrrr! Of course, me hearty! What can I do for ye?"),
        new ChatRequestUserMessage("What's the best way to train a parrot?"),
    }
};

await foreach (StreamingChatCompletionsUpdate chatUpdate in client.GetChatCompletionsStreaming(chatCompletionsOptions))
{
    if (chatUpdate.Role.HasValue)
    {
        Console.Write($"{chatUpdate.Role.Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant()}: ");
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chatUpdate.ContentUpdate))
    {
        Console.Write(chatUpdate.ContentUpdate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap your code inside the controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using OpenAI;
using OpenAI.Chat;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ChatController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<string>>> GetChatCompletions()
    {
        var client = new OpenAIClient(nonAzureOpenAIApiKey, new OpenAIClientOptions());
        var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
        {
            DeploymentName = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            Messages =
            {
                new ChatRequestSystemMessage("You are a helpful assistant. You will talk like a pirate."),
                new ChatRequestUserMessage("Can you help me?"),
                new ChatRequestAssistantMessage("Arrrr! Of course, me hearty! What can I do for ye?"),
                new ChatRequestUserMessage("What's the best way to train a parrot?"),
            }
        };

        var responses = new List<string>();

        await foreach (StreamingChatCompletionsUpdate chatUpdate in client.GetChatCompletionsStreaming(chatCompletionsOptions))
        {
            if (chatUpdate.Role.HasValue)
            {
                responses.Add($"{chatUpdate.Role.Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant()}: ");
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chatUpdate.ContentUpdate))
            {
                responses.Add(chatUpdate.ContentUpdate);
            }
        }

        return Ok(responses);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to hardcode the message and pass that as a body then you can do something like this

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using OpenAI;
using OpenAI.Chat;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ChatController : ControllerBase
{
    public class ChatRequest
    {
        public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<string>>> PostChatCompletions([FromBody] ChatRequest request)
    {
        var client = new OpenAIClient(nonAzureOpenAIApiKey, new OpenAIClientOptions());
        var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
        {
            DeploymentName = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            Messages = new List<ChatRequestMessage>()
        };

        foreach (var message in request.Messages)
        {
            chatCompletionsOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatRequestUserMessage(message));
        }

        var responses = new List<string>();

        await foreach (StreamingChatCompletionsUpdate chatUpdate in client.GetChatCompletionsStreaming(chatCompletionsOptions))
        {
            if (chatUpdate.Role.HasValue)
            {
                responses.Add($"{chatUpdate.Role.Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant()}: ");
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chatUpdate.ContentUpdate))
            {
                responses.Add(chatUpdate.ContentUpdate);
            }
        }

        return Ok(responses);
    }
}
```

Remember the above implementation of the API does not support streaming responses. It waits for all the chat completions to be received from the OpenAI API, then sends them all at once to the client.

Streaming responses to the client as they are received from the OpenAI API would require a different approach. This could be achieved using Server-Sent Events (SSE) or a similar technology, but it's important to note that not all clients and network environments support these technologies.

Here's a simplified example of how you could implement this using Server-Sent Events in ASP.NET Core:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task PostChatCompletions([FromBody] ChatRequest request)
{
    var client = new OpenAIClient(nonAzureOpenAIApiKey, new OpenAIClientOptions());
    var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
    {
        DeploymentName = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        Messages = new List<ChatRequestMessage>()
    };

    foreach (var message in request.Messages)
    {
        chatCompletionsOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatRequestUserMessage(message));
    }

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");

    await foreach (StreamingChatCompletionsUpdate chatUpdate in client.GetChatCompletionsStreaming(chatCompletionsOptions))
    {
        if (chatUpdate.Role.HasValue)
        {
            await Response.WriteAsync($"data: {chatUpdate.Role.Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant()}: \n\n");
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chatUpdate.ContentUpdate))
        {
            await Response.WriteAsync($"data: {chatUpdate.ContentUpdate}\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```